# "High up in the trees" vs "high up the trees"

Tags: grammar

"There was an eagle high up in the trees."

"There was an eagle high up the trees."

I am wondering if both means the same thing and we can omit "in". In my opinion, we can, but I am not so sure you can do that. Also, I am not sure both have the same meaning. I am thinking I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"High up the trees" isn't idiomatic. "High up a/the tree" (singular) could work. It locates something high in a particular tree.
You might use it like this:
"The cat was high up a tree after fleeing the dog."

The use of "up" without "in" suggests that something has climbed the tree, whereas an eagle would have flown there.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, if you read the second sentence, it sounds awkward. While the first sentence flows perfectly well.

Also...

A better way to write it: "An eagle was perched high up in the trees."